# How to check if C++ smart pointer memory allocation was successful?

Tags: c++, c++11, new-operator, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

Consider the following usage of smart pointer `std::unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<char> sp(new(std::nothrow) char[sz]);
```

How can I check if the `new` was successful?

I have two options:

1. Method 1 - Check for bool value: `if(!sp){}`
2. Method 2 - Compare against null pointer: `if(sp==nullptr){}`

---

### Example ([source](https://ideone.com/EuScCq))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    constexpr long long sz = 1000000e10;
    
    //raw pointer
    auto ptr = new(std::nothrow) char[sz];
    if(ptr==nullptr)
    {
        cout<<"ptr nullptr"<<endl;
    }
    
    //smart pointer
    std::unique_ptr<char> sp(new(std::nothrow) char[sz]);
    
    if(!sp)
    {
        cout<<"sp nullptr bool"<<endl;
    }
    
    if(sp==nullptr)
    {
        cout<<"sp nullptr =="<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
    
}
```

### Output:

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 4396KB
ptr nullptr
sp nullptr bool
sp nullptr ==
```

Clearly both Method 1 and Method 2 seem to work.

I would however like to read from an authoritative source (C++ standard, msdn, gcc documentation) that this indeed is the correct way.

Comment: 800 rep and you still don't know you're not supposed to post _images_ of code?

Comment: I wasn't able to format it. This is the first time I have faced such formatting issue in stackoverflow. Therefore I also included a link to ideone.

Comment: `if(sp){}` checks if the allocation was successful and `if(sp==nullptr){}` checks if it *wasn't* successful.

Comment: @SahilSingh Copy&paste it into the question, select it, then press `{}` button to format it.

Comment: @SahilSingh Judging from your question, you don't seem to know that. If you want those two methods to do the same thing, the first one should be `if (!sp)` instead.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat corrected that logical error. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @dandan78 The issue was browser specific, tried formatting the code on my `Firefox 60.0.2` browser, and formatting worked as usual (the same way I have been doing it for several years)

Comment: The question is not about my code not working. It is about recommended way of doing something, to prevent writing sub-optimal code which may fail in future.

Comment: @dandan78 Before posting image of code here are the things I tried. 
1. Checked if any hidden unicode character is putting off SO's formatting logic.
2. Manually added 4 spaces before each line instead of using `{}` button.
3. Tried using HTML <code></code> tag.
4. Tried indenting my code with just tabs, then just spaces, worrying that a mix of tabs and spaces might be messing up the formatting.
none of the methods worked.

Comment: At this point this question is certainly not as bad as the downvotes it had gotten earlier, and yet I doubt anyone will undo their downvotes :-(

Comment: @einpoklum 1001 reasons to get the question right the first time... If a question wastes peoples time, even if it gets fixed later, it still wasted their time.  If it's a good question it'll get up voted later by others and might end up net positive

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I, as an authoritative source, can confirm that both ways are indeed correct.

Just kidding: `std::unique_ptr`'s [`operator ==(std::nullptr_t)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator_cmp) and [`operator bool`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator_bool) are overloaded to perform what you'd expect from a pointer, so yes, both are correct, although method 1 is more idiomatic.

Comment: ha! as an authoritative source. i'm hoping you'll have this on-hold post turn-around with your answer. :) +1